# Set ScrollView inset based on dynamic height of "toolbar" at the bottom of the screen

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with an `.overlay` aligned to `.bottom`.

This overlay acts as a toolbar uses an `.ultraThinMaterial` as a background.

At the moment if I don't do anything the `ScrollView` will "rest" with content underneath the toolbar.

I can get around this by setting `.padding(.bottom, 100)` on the contents of the `ScrollView`.

But... the height of the toolbar can (and will) change dynamically.

I'd like to be able to get the height of the toolbar and set that as the padding of the contents of the `ScrollView` so that the contents isn't overlapped when it scrolls to the bottom.

Is this possible? I think I may have to use GeometryReader for this? Possibly?

Is it possible to use `Toolbar` for this and have a dynamic toolbar height? I've only ever used `Toolbar` with a fixed height.

This is my scroll view currently...

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        // dynamic amount of content here in the scroll view
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .padding(.bottom, 100) // <- How do I make this dynamic also?
}
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack {
        // dynamic amount of content here in the footer
    }
    .padding()
    .background(.thinMaterial)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using `.overlay()` here? The code you shared will let the content of the `ScrollView` run below the toolbar in this way but your explanation makes me believe you want to avoid that (hence the padding at the bottom.)

If that is what you are trying to avoid then something like this would achieve the same thing:

```
VStack(spacing:0) {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            // dynamic amount of content here in the scroll view

        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.bottom, 100) // <- How do I make this dynamic also? // Doesn't seem needed in this version?
    }
    VStack {
        // dynamic amount of content here in the footer

    }
    .padding()
    .background(.thinMaterial)
}
```

Comment: This works but now the content doesn't pass under the "footer" like it should. It's definitely a possible fallback. Although, I believe this also breaks the interaction between the scroll view and the navigation bar. The navigation bar doesn't appear when the scroll view moves into it.

Comment: Trying to understand fully. 
You need the content to still be able to scroll bellow the toolbar but not at rest? What would happen in case the content needs a lot of space? 
This shouldn't pose any issue with navigation bar I believe, as the ScrollView height would adapt to the space available.

Comment: It does cause an issue with the nav bar. When you scroll down the content it moves into the same space as the nav bar and the nav bar doesn't become opaque so the content and the nav bar content collide. I'm trying to create something similar to the `Toolbar` in iOS which has a material background. So you can still see the content blurred behind it. But it will allow the content of the toolbar to grow.